# jump to the last line of imports section

Tags: vim

Often times, when I am writing the source code, I need to jump to the imports section at the top of source code, most the time I'll use `gg`, then move to the last line of the import section, I am wondering is there a shortcut for this common operation?

Comment: `gg}` should do what you want.

Comment: Similar to what @romainl suggest, `gg}-`. The `-` will move to the start of the previous line.

Answer (score 1):

how about using

```
G?^import<space><cr>
```

if you use it 77 times a day, make a mapping.

Answer (score 0):

With my [CountJump plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3130), you can easily define custom motions (as well as text objects) for regions that match a regular expression; e.g. the `import ...` lines:

```
:call CountJump#Region#Motion#MakeBracketMotion('', 'i', 'I', '^\s*import\s', 1)
```

With this, you can jump to the start of an `import` block via `]i`, and to its end via `]I`.